# Safari rotate3d GPU composition bug

Tags: css, canvas, safari, hardware-acceleration

When applying transform: rotate3d(x, y, z, angle) on a block element with z-index: 2 absolutely positioned above an absolutely positioned canvas with z-index: 1, I get this weird GPU composition bug in Safari where a part of the block element isn't rendered (or maybe below the canvas). I've made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzkvY/4/) that clearly demonstrates the bug in Safari. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome. The CSS is as follows:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and maybe supply a potential fix? I've tried almost everything from applying translate3d(0, 0, 0) to changing the globalCompositeOperation of the canvas. It's worth noting if I replace the canvas with a block element that has a background image instead, the bug doesn't appear. It must have something to do with the canvas.

I'm using Safari 7.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Looking forward to hearing from you – thanks!